# I do not see the same in Emulator, according to Android Studio's preview or Android phone

Tags: android, xml

I am learning from `Udacity`, I have learned so far `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout`. Based on this I tried to create an `xml` for a project. I created it according to preview from inside `Android Studio` `Nexus 5X`. Then when I run this in `Emulator Nexus 5X` again I see different output the project was created according to `API 15`. Then when I run it on my Android phone I see it as on preview. Following I will post the outcomes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/background" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/topScore"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="5">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/topImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/topscore" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="0 - 0"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textSize="26dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/arrowRightScore"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/arrowLeftScore"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float" />

        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="390dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/row" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/row1"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/row1"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/row1"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/row1"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="SHOTS"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/arrowLeftRow1"
                android:layout_width="52dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/row1"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/arrowLeftRow1"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/row1"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-35dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="#ffff"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/arrowRightRow1"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/row1"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/row1"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/arrowRightRow1"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/row1"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/row1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-45dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="#ffff"
                android:textSize="18dp" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="390dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/row" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textRow2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/row2"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/row2"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/row2"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/row2"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="FOULS"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/arrowLeftRow2"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/row2"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/row2"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/row2"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/arrowLeftRow2"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/row2"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-45dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="#ffff"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/arrowRightRow2"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/row2"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/row2"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/arrowRightRow2"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/row2"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/row2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-45dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="#ffff"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="390dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/row" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textRow3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/row3"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/row3"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/row3"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/row3"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="CORNERS"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/arrowLeftRow3"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/row3"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/row3"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/row3"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/arrowLeftRow3"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/row3"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-45dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="#ffff"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/arrowRightRow3"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/row3"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/row3"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/arrowRightRow3"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/row3"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/row3"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-45dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="#ffff"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="390dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/row" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textRow4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/row4"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/row4"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/row4"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/row4"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="OFFSIDES"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/arrowLeftRow4"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/row4"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/row4"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/row4"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/arrowLeftRow4"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/row4"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-45dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="#ffff"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/arrowRightRow4"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/row4"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/row4"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/arrowRightRow4"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/row4"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/row4"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-45dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="#ffff"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonReset"
            android:layout_width="150sp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@drawable/reset"
            android:text="RESET"
            android:textColor="#cdc2b1"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

`What I get from preview:`

[image]

`What I get from Emulator:`

[image]

`What I get from my Android Phone:`

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your issue with the layout? I mean what exactly does look different? The only thing I see is the Toolbar, which you can hide ;).

Comment: The arrows are not centered properly on emulator!

Comment: Oh now I see it. My bad! I'll have a look at it and hopefully find the issue!

Comment: Is it a bug? I do not know... I am not sure why I can not see it right in Emulator but I see it as expected from my android phone.

Comment: I will take a look at it in about an hour then I have time! Sorry for my late response

Comment: Your main issue is that you are using static images, inside of which you place your arrows. Depending on the device this scales differently. Unfortunately this leads to your icons being out of place. Solving this would involve rethinking your whole design or defining custom styles for your views which will give them an appearance which looks like your images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I have used on top

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

That pushed 10dp the layout inside. Then I used static `390dp` in `RelativeLayout` and that probably pushed outside the image living the arrows out of place.

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="390dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
```

By removing `android:layout_margin="10dp"` from top `LinearLayout` it looked fine now in Android's Studio emulator also! So in case you see similar problem check margins in **parent Layouts**